Установка python 3.11 на Linux Mint
На моём  компьютере самая новая версия python - 3.9. Мне нужно установить версию 3.11. Как мне это сделать не используя sudo? Пробовал скачивать отсюда https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.9/ и сбилдить по инструкции, но там тоже нужна sudo. Я полный чайник в Linux, поэтому если есть решение, напишите его как можно подробнее, пожалуйста))

pyenv?

Для его установки тоже нужна sudo

А в чем проблема с использованием sudo?

Интересно, откуда у вас 3.9 взялась (без sudo), насколько я помню с минтом раньше шли версии 3.6, 3.8, сейчас 3.10 (в новых версиях возможно уже на 3.12 перейдут)

В общем, вот такое нагуглилось: https://github.com/bjia56/portable-python. Из релизов скачиваете linux-x86_64.zip архив, распаковываете, используете.
